# Injecting tenant information in a SignalR Hub's OnConnected/OnDisconnected

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub

There is a multi-tenant SaaS app where I want to create groups for each `tenantId`s in the SignalR Hub's `OnConnectedAsync`/`OnDisconnectedAsync` hook.

The problem is that `ITenancyContext<ApplicationTenant>` is registered as a scoped service, which means it is only available within the scope of a request. In the context of a SignalR hub, it is not associated with a request, and thus it is not available.

So how do I make it available? Authorize it and enrich the claims somehow?

```cs
public sealed class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    readonly ILogger<NotificationHub> _logger;
    readonly Guid _tenantId;

    public NotificationHub(ILogger<NotificationHub> logger, ITenancyContext<ApplicationTenant> tenancyContext) => (_logger, _tenantId) = (logger, tenancyContext.Tenant.Id);

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        await JoinGroup(_tenantId.ToString());
        _logger.LogInformation("{ConnectionId} has connected to the hub. TenantId: {TenantId}", Context.ConnectionId, _tenantId);
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception)
    {
        await LeaveGroup(_tenantId.ToString());
        _logger.LogInformation("{ConnectionId} was disconnected from the hub. TenantId: {TenantId}", Context.ConnectionId, _tenantId);
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }

    Task JoinGroup(string groupName) => Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);

    Task LeaveGroup(string groupName) => Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can create a middleware to implement it. Inject `ITenancyContext<ApplicationTenant>` in this middlerware, let call it `TenantMiddleware`.

```
public class TenantMiddleware
{
    private readonly ITenancyContext<ApplicationTenant> _tenancyContext;

    public TenantMiddleware(ITenancyContext<ApplicationTenant> tenancyContext)
    {
        _tenancyContext = tenancyContext;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, Func<Task> next)
    {
        var user = context.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        if (user != null)
        {
            var TenantId= _tenancyContext.Tenant.Id;
            user.AddClaim(new Claim("TenantId", TenantId.ToString()));
        }

        await next();
    }
}
```

Then we can use it in your `NotificationHub` class.

```
public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
    // Get TenantId like below.
    var user = Context.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    var tenantIdClaim = user?.FindFirst("TenantId");
    _tenantId = tenantIdClaim != null ? Guid.Parse(tenantIdClaim.Value) : Guid.Empty;
    ...
    await JoinGroup(_tenantId.ToString());
    _logger.LogInformation("{ConnectionId} has connected to the hub. TenantId: {TenantId}", Context.ConnectionId, _tenantId);
    await base.OnConnectedAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that solution! What I ended up doing was add `accessTokenFactory: () => authUser.accessToken || ''` in the frontend which sends the JWT token to the backend and then handling it in the backend. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-7.0. I wonder if I should put it in an answer

Comment: @nop The question you started doesn't mention Authentication, nor does it say that there is a JWT. So my answer is the conventional way of thinking about this question. If it also could solves your problem, I think you can accept it as an answer too.

Comment: @nop Of course you can also post your solution and I will upvote it. In this way, community members who encounter similar problems can have two options to deal with this problem. I think this is also very good.

Comment: Thank you! I did that :)

Answer (score 1):

I followed up the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-7.0#bearer-token-authentication because I realized `Context.User.Claims` was empty which was the issue.

I had to add JWT authorization after which `Context.User.Claims` has finally returned the actual claims, so they were no longer empty. I basically got the tenant ID from there. As much as I understand, when I authorized the hub with a JWT token, it resolved the claims from there.

```
const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(`${apiRoutes.root}/${HUB_NAME}`, {
        skipNegotiation: true,
        transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
        accessTokenFactory: () => authUser.accessToken || ''
    })
    .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
    .withAutomaticReconnect()
    .build();
```

```cs
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public sealed class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    readonly ILogger<NotificationHub> _logger;
    
    public NotificationHub(ILogger<NotificationHub> logger) => _logger = logger;
    
    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        var tenant = Context.User.GetTenant();
        await JoinGroup(tenant);
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
    
    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception)
    {
        var tenant = Context.User.GetTenant();
        await LeaveGroup(tenant);
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
    
    Task JoinGroup(string groupName) => Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    
    Task LeaveGroup(string groupName) => Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
}
```

```cs
events.OnMessageReceived = context =>
{
    var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
    var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && path.StartsWithSegments(Constants.NotificationHubUrl))
    {
        context.Token = accessToken;
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
};
```

Hope it helps someone.